# I am not able to boot my windows(it is on boot menu) after partitioning the hdd in Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu on windows 10, and set the partitioning in Ubuntu, and there is a partition (ntfs, bootable) (containing wimdows10 files), and the boot menu shows the option for booting windows10 ,but after clicking it is not able to load it.. 
Plz help me.. my father won't forgive me...

Comment: Did you turn fast start up off in Windows. That is always on hibernation. And Windows may turn it back on with updates. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions So if UEFI you can directly boot Windows from UEFI. But if old BIOS install, you have to temporarily install Windows boot loader, fix Windows &  then reinstall grub. Boot-Repair can do most, but best to have Windows repair disk or installer with repair console. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix windows boot loader. Insert windows Installation disk or USB, click on *repair my window* and open Command Prompt. Just type :

```
bootrec.exe /fixMbr
exit
```

remove installation media (USB/disk). And, restart your system. Windows will be running like charm. Now you have to fix your Grub for ubuntu. Install tool EasyBCD [Downloading link](https://www.techspot.com/downloads/3112-easybcd.html), select linux and grub2 for boot menu. Restart your system. It will ask for Ubuntu or Windows before Windows Startup Screen. Switch to ubuntu and write this in your terminal.

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now, Grub is fixed. you can uninstall EasyBCD later.